# Can one define an uncountable infinite product?

Tags: integration, continuity, infinite-product

The continuous version of a sum is commonly called an integral. But what would be the continuous version of a product? The same question in "pictures":
$$
\sum \rightarrow \int
$$
$$
\prod \rightarrow ??
$$
I thought that maybe one could argue as follows: 
$$
\prod_n a_n = e^{\ln \prod_n a_n} = e^{\sum_n \ln a_n} \rightarrow e^{\int \ln a(n) dn}
$$
So the continuous version of a product could be defined like
$$
\prod \rightarrow e^{\int \ln}
$$
Does this make sense?

Comment: Makes sense. ${}{}{}$

Comment: [It appears it can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral).